# Any Crystal Report Scheduler that has OLEDB capabilities?

Tags: crystal-reports

I use Crystal Reports 10 Pro but I need a scheduler that can connect to my report services using OLEDB connections for my parameters.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options available.

1. You could buy Crystal Server. It has a scheduler built in. (~£4,000)
2. There are off the shelf products on the net that you can buy. (~£400)
3. Use .NET to write your own.